# Could not create archive for project with Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, swift, ipa

I try to create `IPA` file for my application.

At first i try to make archive. It creates good for Application with extension, but when i try to add my custom Cocoa Touch Framework (with at least one .swift file, even empty), Xcode says that **"error: underlying Objective-C module 'View' not found"** By the way, with empty framework it works well.

**Where is my mistake?**

My steps are next:
I set Provision Profile in project 
[image]

Then i select "iOS Device" and push "Archive" button.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Dare I say this is a Bug in Beta 5?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by removing MyFramework.h that is created automatically by the Xcode Template.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But it's still wrong behaviour as for me.